# Getting the current global messages from FacesContext

Tags: java, jsf, facescontext

I have a problem. I need to know whether my page has global errors or not. This is because I have 2 different `h:messages` (error containers)

```
<h:messages id="errorMsgsContainer"
layout="table" 
rendered="true"
styleClass="message-container error-message" 
infoClass="info" 
errorClass=" error" warnClass="warn-message warn" globalOnly="true"/>

<h:messages id="errorMsgsContainerValidation"
layout="table" 
styleClass="message-container error-message-validation" 
infoClass="info" 
errorClass="error" globalOnly="false"/>
```

One will show the business related messages and the other will just show the validation messages. There are two `messages` because of business requirements.

When validation error messages are produced, the facelet works fine, because one of the `messages` tag has the `globalOnly="true"` attribute-value pair.

The problem comes when I've a global-only error. It will appear in both boxes.

I want to know if any of there errors are global, so I don't show the validation container till the global errors are fixed by the user on my form.

I've tried to get it through the `FacesContext` with

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getMessageList().get(i).getSeverity()
```

and some other commands but it does not seem to work.

Please help me to solve this problem. How can I get the current global messages list, so I can know if there is any global error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> When validation error messages are produced, the facelet works fine, because one of the messages tag has the globalOnly="true" attribute-value pair.

This is incorrect. You are seeing messages for validation errors, in the other `h:messages` tag with the `globalOnly="false"` attribute-value pair. Validation messages always have a client Id, which happens to be the Id of the form element that failed validation, and hence will be displayed in a `messages` tag that allows non-global messages to be displayed, or has the value of the `for` attribute set to the applicable Id.

> The problem comes when I've a global-only error. It will appear in both boxes.

This is expected behavior. I believe you've confused the meaning of the `globalOnly` attribute. When the value of the `globalOnly` attribute is true, only global messages (i.e. messages without a client Id) will be displayed; when the value is false, global messages will be displayed in addition to other messages that are already queued. This would explain why global messages are displayed twice - the first `h:messages` tag would display the global message because it should display only global messages, and the second would display it because it can display it.

> Please help me to solve this problem. How can I get the current global messages list, so I can know if there is any global error?

If you want to continue having two `h:messages` tags in your facelet, then you can use a "pseudo-global" Id when queuing your `FacesMessage`s for display, instead of specifying an Id of `null`; the value of the pseudo-global Id in the following example is `inputForm` which is a valid client Id (of the form) that would not have any validation messages produced in this case:

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage("inputForm", new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Added a global message", null));
```

You can then add a EL expression to render the `messages` tag responsible for display of the input-validation messages:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets" 
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" 
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:fn="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions">
...
    <h:form id="inputForm">
    ...
    </h:form>
    <h:messages id="psuedoGlobalMessages" for="inputForm" globalOnly="true" infoStyle="color:green" errorStyle="color:red" warnClass="color:orange" />
    <h:messages id="clientMessages" rendered="#{fn:length(facesContext.getMessageList('inputForm')) == 0}" globalOnly="false" infoStyle="color:green" errorStyle="color:red" warnClass="color:orange" />
...
```

Note, the use of the `globalOnly` attribute in only one `messages` tag. The same `messages` tag is also not displayed if a pseudo-global message is queued up for display via the EL expression specified in the `rendered` attribute. You can also use the client Id of a hidden form element created specifically to direct all pseudo-global messages, instead of the form's client Id.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
rendered="#{not empty facesContext.getMessageList('inputForm')}
```

instead of:

```
rendered="#{fn:length(facesContext.getMessageList('inputForm')) == 0}"
```

in the Vineet Reynolds's answer.